# Flash Builder: conditional compilation - app.xml

Tags: flash-builder, conditional-compilation

I have a flash project that shall target different platforms. However - code is not completely the same for the different platforms.

using compiler statements and config blocks like

```
CONFIG::MOBILE{
    ...mobile specific code here...
}
```

I can easily maintain the different versions within the same project.

However - there should also be different mainapp-app.xml files be used for the different versions - or depending on the compiler flags different content within the mainapp-app.xml

how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question. Indeed, you can create multiple config.xml files in your project and link to these config files via compiler arguments. I generally use ANT to do this as it makes the build process simple. But if you don't have ANT setup, simply right click on your project, select **ActionScript Compiler** and add the following to the list of additional compiler arguments:

-load-config+=config/mainapp-app.xml

Note that the config folder is relative to the project root. I generally put my config files in this folder. I wrote a detailed post on how to perform conditional compilation in AS3 on my blog. Visit http://www.willjohnson.me/blog/?p=146 for detailed instructions.

I hope this answered your question.

Regards,

Will